# Automate Native Range Partitioning in PostgreSQL 10 for Zabbix 3.4

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, zabbix, database-partitioning, postgresql-10

I would like to automate the process of partitioning a Zabbix 3.4 Database using PostgreSQL's Native Range Partitioning.

Would it be wiser to write a SQL function to perform the following below or to use a shell/python script?

- Make sure at least one partition is created ahead of what's needed.
- Delete any partition older than *x* weeks/months; for `history` 7 days and for `trends` 1 year

Comment: Welcome! It is unclear what you are asking. Are you having a particular problem with your code, or are you getting a specific error?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome @kismert; I am looking for help to develop a script for the code provided. I updated the post; hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: DribblzAroundU82 - thanks for the update. This site is more for programmers to get answers about problems they are having with their code. It is not really a place to solicit someone to write a program for you. If you have a problem with code that you are writing to solve this problem, please share the code, and let us know what the problem is.

Comment: @kismert ok thanks for the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written detailed notes on using PostgreSQL version 11 together with [pgpartman](https://github.com/pgpartman/pg_partman) as the mechanism for native table partitioning with Zabbix (version 3.4 as of this writing).

[zabbix-postgres-partitioning](https://github.com/Doctorbal/zabbix-postgres-partitioning)

Answer (score 1):

The following below is the solution I came up with for transitioning to PSQL 10 Native Range Partitioning from a PSQL 9.4 populated database with no partitioning.

A. Create a Zabbix Empty PSQL 10 Database.

Ensure you **first** create an empty Zabbix PSQL 10 DB.

```
# su postgres
postgres@<>:~$ createuser -P -s -e zabbix
postgres@<>:~$ psql
postgres# create database zabbix;
postgres# grant all privileges on database zabbix to zabbix;
```

B. Create tables & Native Range Partitions on `clock` column

Create the tables in the Zabbix DB and implement native range partitioning for the clock column. Below is an example of a manual SQL script that can be fun for `history` table. Perform this for all the `history` tables you want to partition via range.

```
zabbix=# CREATE TABLE public.history
(
    itemid bigint NOT NULL,
    clock integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    value numeric(20,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)::numeric,
    ns integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) PARTITION BY RANGE (clock);

zabbix=# CREATE TABLE public.history_old PARTITION OF public.history
    FOR VALUES FROM (MINVALUE) TO (1522540800);
zabbix=# CREATE TABLE public.history_y2018m04 PARTITION OF public.history
    FOR VALUES FROM (1522540800) TO (1525132800);
zabbix=# CREATE TABLE public.history_y2018m05 PARTITION OF public.history
    FOR VALUES FROM (1525132800) TO (1527811200);

zabbix=# CREATE INDEX ON public.history_old USING btree (itemid, clock);
zabbix=# CREATE INDEX ON public.history_y2018m04 USING btree (itemid, clock);
zabbix=# CREATE INDEX ON public.history_y2018m05 USING btree (itemid, clock);
```

C. Automate it!

I used a shell script because it is one of the simplest ways to deal with creating new partitions in PSQL 10. Make sure you're always at least one partition ahead of what's needed.

Let's call the script `auto_history_tables_monthly.sh`.

On a Debian 8 Flavor OS that runs PSQL 10 ensure the script is in a certain directory (I used `/usr/local/bin`) with correct permissions (`chown postgres:postgres /usr/local/bin/auto_history_tables_monthly.sh`) and make it executable (`chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/auto_history_tables_monthly.sh` as `postgres` user).

Create a cron job (`crontab -e`) for `postgres` user with following:

```
0 0 1 * * /usr/local/bin/auto_history_tables_monthly.sh | psql -d zabbix
```

This will run the shell script the first of every month.

Below is the script. It uses the `date` command to leverage the UTC epoch value. It creates a table a month in advance and drops a partition 2 months older. This appears to work well in conjunction with a 31 days of retention for `history` that is customized to my needs. Ensure the PSQL 10 DB is on UTC time for this use case.

```
#!/bin/bash

month_diff () {
        year=$1
  month=$2
        delta_month=$3
  x=$((12*$year+10#$month-1))
        x=$((x+$delta_month))
        ry=$((x/12))
        rm=$(((x % 12)+1))
        printf "%02d %02d\n" $ry $rm
}

month_start () {
        year=$1
  month=$2
        date '+%s' -d "$year-$month-01 00:00:00" -u
}

month_end () {
        year=$1
  month=$2
        month_start $(month_diff $year $month 1)
}

# Year using date
current_year=$(date +%Y)
current_month=$(date +%m)

# Math
next_date=$(month_diff $current_year $current_month 1)
next_year=$(echo $next_date|sed 's/ .*//')
next_month=$(echo $next_date|sed 's/.* //')

start=$(month_start $next_date)
end=$(month_end $next_date)

#next_month_table="public.history_y${next_year}m${next_month}"

# Create next month table for history, history_uint, history_str, history_log, history_text
sql="
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.history_y${next_year}m${next_month} PARTITION OF public.history
      FOR VALUES FROM ($start) TO ($end);
    \nCREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.history_uint_y${next_year}m${next_month} PARTITION OF public.history_uint
      FOR VALUES FROM ($start) TO ($end);
    \nCREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.history_str_y${next_year}m${next_month} PARTITION OF public.history_str
      FOR VALUES FROM ($start) TO ($end);
    \nCREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.history_log_y${next_year}m${next_month} PARTITION OF public.history_log
      FOR VALUES FROM ($start) TO ($end);
    \nCREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.history_text_y${next_year}m${next_month} PARTITION OF public.history_text
      FOR VALUES FROM ($start) TO ($end);
    \nCREATE INDEX on public.history_y${next_year}m${next_month} USING btree (itemid, clock);
    \nCREATE INDEX on public.history_uint_y${next_year}m${next_month} USING btree (itemid, clock);
    \nCREATE INDEX on public.history_str_y${next_year}m${next_month} USING btree (itemid, clock);
    \nCREATE INDEX on public.history_log_y${next_year}m${next_month} USING btree (itemid, clock);
    \nCREATE INDEX on public.history_text_y${next_year}m${next_month} USING btree (itemid, clock);
    "

echo -e $sql

# Math
prev_date=$(month_diff $current_year $current_month -2)
prev_year=$(echo $prev_date|sed 's/ .*//')
prev_month=$(echo $prev_date|sed 's/.* //')

# Drop last month table for history, history_uint, history_str, history_log, history_text
sql="
    DROP TABLE public.history_y${prev_year}m${prev_month};
    \nDROP TABLE public.history_uint_y${prev_year}m${prev_month};
    \nDROP TABLE public.history_str_y${prev_year}m${prev_month};
    \nDROP TABLE public.history_log_y${prev_year}m${prev_month};
    \nDROP TABLE public.history_text_y${prev_year}m${prev_month};
    "

echo -e $sql
```

D. Then dump the data from the old database within. I used `pg_dump/pg_restore`.

I'm sure there are more complex solutions out there but I found this to be simplest for the needs of autopartitioning the Zabbix Database using the PostgreSQL 10 Native Range Partitioning functionality.

Please let me know if you need more details.